# Way to programmatically send updates to people who Facebook "like"-ed web pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Now that we have Facebook Like buttons on web pages all over the place, is there a way to send updates to people who have liked those pages?  I haven't seen/heard about this ability but it seems like it'd be the natural next step.

Comment: I think this blog post is exactly what you're looking for:
[How-To: Publish updates to people who like your Open Graph Page](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/465)